# return La-TeX base PDFs to text or TeX

Tags: pdf

PDF articles of scientific articles (usually written in LaTeX) include the following

- Formula
- Footnote
- Headline
- Page Number

Is there software to convert these pdfs to `text` or `LaTeX`? (Preferably free)

PDF to text converter software combines everything together, for example page number combines with text, or misdiagnoses formulas

If I find software that returns pdfs (that written with LaTeX) to LaTeX, it is very suitable

Comment: LaTeX is not a format that is good as destination for reversing a document as placing elements at certain positions on the page is very difficult (LaTeX is not designed to giv you the full control where to place which element). And PDf is bad for reversing as a PDF document is just bunch of text and image elements somewhere placed on the page without any relation to each other. Modern OCR programs are re rebuild a very similar Word document but I doubt that this is possible for LaTeX, especially when formulas are used.